# Capistrano 3: Run task only on a single server from a pool of servers assigned a role

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I have 20 servers that are in the "web" role.  I have a task I need to perform on only one of them as the change affects shared storage.  My current solution is a hack to get around this (below).  Looking for a better way, I don't have a ton of ruby or cap experience.

```
task :checkout_project_properties do
    num_runs = 0
    on roles(:web), in: :sequence do
        if num_runs > 0
            abort('Only running on one server.  Exiting')
        end
        execute("checkout-project-properties #{uc_stage} #{repo} #{branch}")
        num_runs += 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I assume that you are referring to your production configuration, with so many web servers. In this case, your `config/deploy/production.rb` probably contains many lines like this:

```ruby
server 'web_1', roles: %w(web)
server 'web_2', roles: %w(web)
server 'web_3', roles: %w(web)
...
```

Simply make one of these servers primary, so it looks like:

```ruby
server 'web_1', roles: %w(web), primary: true
server 'web_2', roles: %w(web)
server 'web_3', roles: %w(web)
...
```

Then change your task so it looks like this:

```ruby
task :checkout_project_properties do
    on primary(:web) do
        execute("checkout-project-properties #{uc_stage} #{repo} #{branch}")
    end
end
```

Comment: Not working for me :'( I've tried with or without the `(:web)`, and other combinations. Might it be because I'm doing an `invoke` instead of an `execute`?

Comment: What can you do if you want to run on any server of any role ? It seems like the `primary` method must take an argument