# Capistrano deploy to all servers but run some tasks on only one

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I was deploying my Symfony2 application on one server only for a few month and it was perfect, but as I've added more servers, I'm stuck when I want to update all my servers at the same time, but run some commands only once (like database migration, and assets generation and push to S3).

Here are my servers:

```
server '192.168.0.100', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{app db web toto}
server '192.168.0.101', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{app db web}
```

And here is one custom task I have in my `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :specific do
    task :command do
        on roles(:all) do |host|
            if host.roles.include?(:toto)
                invoke 'symfony:console', 'one:specific:command'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

With `cap --roles=toto staging deploy` but then only one of my two servers were updated.

I've tried the filter method like that:

```
namespace :assets do
    task :increment do
        set :filter, :roles => %w{toto}
        invoke 'symfony:console', 'one:specific:command'
    end
end
```

And other methods, copy pasting from stack overflow answers, but didn't found any matching answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capistrano 3: Run task only on a single server from a pool of servers assigned a role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095865/capistrano-3-run-task-only-on-a-single-server-from-a-pool-of-servers-assigned-a)

Answer (score 7):

I might have hesitated longer, as this answer is not working. And I'm still unable to find a solution, in any other post, SO question, or Capistrano documentation...

---

I hesitated to post this question and finally found my answer. But as it took me a long search, here is the answer:

Just add `primary: true` to one website :

```
server '192.168.0.100', roles: %w{app db web}, primary: true
server '192.168.0.101', roles: %w{app db web}
```

And in the `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :specific do
    task :command do
        on primary(:web) do
            invoke 'symfony:console', 'one:specific:command'
        end
    end
end
```

My command output is still specifying the two servers, but hopefully only one did the specific command:

```
  03 php app/console one:specific:command
✔ 03 ubuntu@192.168.0.100 1.153s
✔ 03 ubuntu@192.168.0.101 6.551s
```

Finally!

Comment: I believe that by default, the first entry is defined as the primary server. So if you want only one server in a particular role to run a task, but you don't care which one it is, then you can omit the primary: true argument.

Comment: @will_in_wi Hum... I'll have to try that too. And maybe this : http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/property-filtering/